# Why does React-Webcam on mobile quality look so bad compared to native mobile camera?

Tags: reactjs, camera, webcam

When using [React-Webcam Demo](https://codepen.io/mozmorris/pen/JLZdoP) on mobile, the quality always looks absolutely terrible compared to Native Mobile Camera.

Is there any way to make React-Webcam, or access the camera from React that's close as possible to native quality? Right now, the webcam feed is extremely grainy and there's no focus option.

Just adding in options like `screenshotQuality`, setting the width/height or aspect ratio still makes it a far cry from native camera quality.

Or is the only option to use something like React Native to access the mobile's actual camera device?

Comment: It works fine for me. Your mobile camera probably uses software enhancement that are not implemented in the browser

Comment: Yeah, I thought that would be the case, it looks ok, but native cameras look infinitely better all the time. Oppo A52 for reference.